# Salesforce lwc lightning/modal dispatchEvent

Tags: salesforce, lwc, custom-events, dispatchevent

Documentation - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-modal/documentation - modal - API 56
When I try to fire an event from the modal window to the parent window - completely according to the example from the documentation - I get an error -

Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': parameter 1 is not of type 'Event'.

Completely according to the example from the documentation

```
this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('select', {
  detail: {
    id: 42
  }
}));
```

The error occurs even at the moment the event is sent - not to mention the moment it is received

I'm waiting for an event but it doesn't happen

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable [Lightning Web Security Enabled](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.security_lwsec_enable) in the org to get this working.

You can check this https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/387924/lightning-modal-custom-event-not-working-in-winter-23-release

I've checked it myself and it's working well.